# Div centred on desktop but fixed to right on mobile. What's happening?

Tags: css, alignment

I'm having a problem with a logo I want centre aligned on a homepage. 
It works fine on desktop but as soon as I look on mobile it fixes itself on the right hand side and falls out of the frame.

Here is the background image:

```css
#homebg { 
  background: url(images/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and here is logo:

```css
#logo {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

My main aim is to get the logo to be centre aligned on all platforms.
Any help would be great!

Comment: left: 50% works because there happens to be extra space on desktop the desktop version. I would look into responsive designing and use a grid system to take care of these issues.

Comment: On which "mobile" (OS & browser) are you seeing this? Without any more knowledge, and with two completely blank examples to run, I can only speculate it might have something to do with the `position: fixed`, which lots of mobile browsers don't like.

Comment: @NicholasYoung, no he's using `transform: translate()` to push it back by a half.

Comment: That said, it's unclear what `#logo` consists of, and probably won't scale with the viewport.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t3yo3b3p/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that on a small screen, 50% is the space to the left of the logo, the logo itself is taking up like 60% of the screen (since the screen is so small) and you're left with overflow to the right.

You can use the CSS calc() function to find out the REAL amount of space needed to center the logo: [css calc tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

What's the width of your logo? (change this to the ACTUAL WIDTH.. I'm just making a guess here) width: 300px;
What's the total width of a computer or a phone screen? 100%
So the space to the left of a perfectly centered logo should be: (100%-300px)/2
Solving the equation we get: 50%-150px

Just fix that one line in your CSS code to say:

```
left: calc(50% - 150px);
```

*THE SPACES AROUND THE - (minus) SIGN ARE IMPORTANT*

The resulting CSS should be:

```
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; /*wait a second .. you want it centered vertically, too?? */
    left: calc(50% - 150px); /* 50% minus "the width of your logo divided by 2" */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */ /* what's this line for? you dont need this line for positioning ... */    }
```

If you don't know how wide `#logo` is, and you need to figure out the exact browser amount, right click on that element in chrome -> click "inspect element" and then click "computed" styles to see the exact width of it. Then, back in your code, make sure to change `left: calc(50% - 150px);` to reflect the width you found out. It should be the width of the element in the "computed styles" section *divided by two*.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately I can't vote up because I have only just joined to find an answer to this question but if anyone else is looking for this (I doubt it!) it works like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
```